# morphism of $C^{\infty}(M)$ algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let M be a differential manifold and $C^{\infty}(M) =\{ f: M \to \mathbb{R}; f \mbox{ is smooth} \}$. Prove that for every $\mathbb{R}$-algebra morphism $\alpha: C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique $p \in M$ such that $\alpha(f) = ev_p(f) = f(p)$.

Comment: Are you sure there is no compacity hypothesis ?

Comment: The exercise don't say anything about M beeing compact =(

Comment: Huh, nice. I never knew about "C-infinity" algebra. I've only met with C* (C-star) algebra.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Simply $C^{\infty}(M)$ is the commutativa algebra with unit of smooth map on $M$; it is not a "particular type" of algebra!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [homomorphisms of $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^{n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524703/homomorphisms-of-c-infty-mathbb-rn)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of an algebraic topology person, @Armandoj18eos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer for the compact case. Notice that $C^\infty(M)/\ker \alpha=\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $\ker \alpha$ is a maximal ideal in $C^\infty(M)$. We will show that every maximal ideal in $C^\infty(M)$ arises as the kernel of a evaluation map $ev_x$ and furthermore that $x$ is unique.

Let $I \subset C^\infty(M)$ be a maximal ideal. Suppose for every $x \in M$ there is a $f \in I$ s.t. $f(x)\neq 0$. By continuity of $f$ there exists a neighborhood of $U_x$ of $x$ s.t. $f$ is nowhere zero on this neighborhood. Cover $M$ with such neighborhoods and by compactness choose a finite subcover. Let $f_i$ be the corresponding function that do not vanish on this neighborhoods. Than it holds that

$$f= f^2_1+\ldots+f^2_n >0$$

and furthermore $ f \in I$ but $f$ is invertible (by $1/f$) and so $I=C^\infty(M)$ a contradiction. Now clearly $I=\ker ev_x$ for some $x$ since both ideals are maximal.

Uniquness follows since $\ker ev_x \neq \ker ev_y$. I think this can be seen by using $\arctan$ in local coordinates and extending appropriately. But I'm too tired to work out the details.

**Added:** For the noncompact case you can make allmost the same arguments: suppose $f_x \in I$ are functions with neighborhoods $U_x$ s.t. the $f_x$ don't vanish on $U_x$. By paracompactness you can assume that $\{U_x\}_{x \in M}$ is a locally finite cover. Choose bump-functions $b_x$ with $supp (b_x)\subset U_x$. Then 
$$f = \sum_{x \in M} b_x f_x^2 >0 $$
is a well defined function and $f \in I$ (if the sum-sign here troubles you pass to a countable subcover which is possible since $M$ has a countable basis, but anyhow this is locally just a finite sum). Now it's similar to above.

Comment: The same argument works almost verbatim for a general paracompact space.

Comment: Yes, I just thought of that. I will add it, thanks!